# Can't make OpenMP work with CodeBlocks and GFortran

Tags: gcc, openmp, codeblocks, gfortran

For some reason, I cant make OpenMP work with CodeBlocks and GFortran. I tried another IDE (Geany) and it works properly, but with CodeBlocks it does not. I must say that I included the `-fopenmp` option in CodeBlocks.

Here is a simple code that I tested.

```
program test
implicit none
integer i

!$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(PRIVATE)
Do i=1,10
Write(*,*) i
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

end program test
```

And here is the build log:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in TEST (compiler: GNU Fortran Compiler)---------------

gfortran.exe -Jobj\Debug\ -Wall  -g  -fopenmp    -c "C:\Users\tilter\Dropbox\Public\Code\Nova pasta\TEST\main.f95" -o obj\Debug\main.o
gfortran.exe  -o bin\Debug\TEST.exe obj\Debug\main.o    
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `test':
C:/Users/tilter/Dropbox/Public/Code/Nova pasta/TEST/main.f95:5: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_start'
C:/Users/tilter/Dropbox/Public/Code/Nova pasta/TEST/main.f95:5: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_end'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/Users/tilter/Dropbox/Public/Code/Nova pasta/TEST/main.f95:6: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_start'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/Users/tilter/Dropbox/Public/Code/Nova pasta/TEST/main.f95:6: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel_end'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/Users/tilter/Dropbox/Public/Code/Nova pasta/TEST/main.f95:8: undefined reference to `omp_get_num_threads'
obj\Debug\main.o:C:/Users/tilter/Dropbox/Public/Code/Nova pasta/TEST/main.f95:8: undefined reference to `omp_get_thread_num'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
6 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

I don't know what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted Windows 7 and it fixed the problem.